# How to put an event inside an event

Tags: c#

So I've started to touch the Windows Forms Application and came from Console Applications

Now I see events and I want to have a line drawn if the key "K" is pressed
but KeyDown is an event and I can't put paint event inside the KeyDown event..

Comment: post your code, of what you have done till now

Comment: You want to call a method from the KeyDown event handler. You can name this method: `DrawLine`. The method body could be f.e.: `using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 20, 20);
}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Don't teach a newbie CreateGraphics.  It will cause problems on their next question.

Comment: removed fluf and tags from the title

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that if your form is resized, it might erase everything:
You can use this code to draw on demand: (Tested code)

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyChar=='K')
   Draw();
}

void Draw()
{
   System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
   System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
   formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
   formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);
   myPen.Dispose();
   formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-handle-multiple-events-using-event-properties) addresses this type of issue via delegates.

> To handle multiple events using event properties Define a delegate
>   collection within the class that raises the events.
>
> Define a key for each event.
>
> Define the event properties in the class that raises the events.
>
> Use the delegate collection to implement the add and remove accessor
>   methods for the event properties.
>
> Use the public event properties to add and remove event handler
>   delegates in the classes that handle the events.